# add record to column in codeigniter if has some dependence

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am having a post that user can send to 'another profile' on site, but before posting it will be added to 'some another profile'of other 'random users' and he must approve this post. 'Random users' will receive this submit for approval only if they already follows this 'another profile'. So, my question is:

> how to check 'random users' follows 'some another profile' to get new requests for approve?

what I have tried this:

another_profile follows table (profile_follows):

```
profile_id | who_follow_id   
21           5
```

post that user submit for approve ( posts_for_approve ):

```
for_whom_id | submit_text | submit_author_id | post_id
21            some text     5                  2
```

users table ( users ):

```
user_id
5
```

and table with users that can approve ( users_can_approve ):

```
post_id | user_id
2         5
```

in my posts_model I'm getting all users:

```
function get_all_users()
{
    $this->db->select('user_id');
    $this->db->order_by('rand()');
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

in my controller I'm getting all users which will receive posts for approve:

```
$all_users = $this->stories_model->get_all_users();
 foreach ($all_users as $key) {
  $send_approve['post_id'] = $edit;
  $send_approve['user_id'] = '';
  $this->db->insert('contribute_moderators', $send_approve);
 }
```

So this works, but in my code ALL site users will receive post for approve, but my need is to check users follows 'profile_id', to receive this post for approval. Thanks!

Comment: Few questions: In profile_follows table 'who_follow_id' refers to user_id in the users table correct?In your controller, what id $edit. And $send_approve['user_id'] is the field you're trying to fill correctly, right?

Comment: @Pacio oh, sorry, `$edit = post_id` of the post that user send to approve, `$send_approve['user_id']` is the column in users_can_approve table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naturally your get_all_users() function gets all the users, which you don't want. You didn't answer my first question of the comment, but I' pretty sure you don't really want results from the users table anyway, you want the user_id from the profile_follows table. I'd rename it get_all_followers() and do something like this:

```
//Note I'm passing the $profile_id to this function, which I assume you have access to
function get_all_followers($profile_id)
{
    $this->db->select('user_id');
    $this->db->order_by('rand()');
    $this->db->where('profile_id' = $profile_id);
    $query = $this->db->get('profile_follows');
    return $query->result_array;
}
```

Controller:

```
$all_followers = $this->stories_model->get_all_followers($profile_id);
foreach ($all_users as $key) {
  $send_approve['post_id'] = $edit;
  $send_approve['user_id'] = $key;  //your answer isn't clear to me, but I think this is where you need your follower user_id
  $this->db->insert('contribute_moderators', $send_approve);
}
```

Comment: fix some issues from your answer, and yes, it works, huge thanks :)

Comment: Glad I could help